# How do I do a custom modelbinder when binding from body?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I've been trying to experiment with model binding to make our API easier to use. When using the API I can't get the model binding to bind when the data is in the body, only when it is part of the query.

The code I have is:

```
public class FunkyModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public bool BindModel(HttpActionContext actionContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        var model = (Funky) bindingContext.Model ?? new Funky();

        var hasPrefix = bindingContext.ValueProvider
                                      .ContainsPrefix(bindingContext.ModelName);
        var searchPrefix = (hasPrefix) ? bindingContext.ModelName + "." : "";
        model.Funk = GetValue(bindingContext, searchPrefix, "Funk");
        bindingContext.Model = model;
        return true;
    }

    private string GetValue(ModelBindingContext context, string prefix, string key)
    {
        var result = context.ValueProvider.GetValue(prefix + key);
        return result == null ? null : result.AttemptedValue;
    }
}
```

When looking at the `ValueProvider` property on the `bindingContext` I only see `QueryStringValueProvider` and `RouteDataValueProvider` which I think means that if the data is in the body I won't get it. How should I do this? I would like to support posting data as either json or form-encoded.

Comment: Could you describe more about your scenario? in webapi, by default data coming from the body is bound via formatters.

Comment: So maybe I should use a formatter for this then?

Comment: yeah..right...take a look at the following article for more details: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jmstall/archive/2012/04/16/how-webapi-does-parameter-binding.aspx

Answer (score 4):

I am looking into this as well.

WebApis Model Binder comes with two built in ValueProviders.

QueryStringValueProviderFactory & RouteDataValueProviderFactory

Which are searched when you call

```
context.ValueProvider.GetValue
```

This question has some code on how to bind data from the body.

[how to pass the result model object out of System.Web.Http.ModelBinding.IModelBinder. BindModel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28892332/how-to-pass-the-result-model-object-out-of-system-web-http-modelbinding-imodelbi)

You could create a custom ValueProvider to do this as well, probably a better idea - which will be searched for the value matching the key. The above link just does this within the model binder, which limits the ModelBinder to looking only in the body.

```
public class FormBodyValueProvider : IValueProvider
{
    private string body;

    public FormBodyValueProvider ( HttpActionContext actionContext )
    {
        if ( actionContext == null ) {
            throw new ArgumentNullException( "actionContext" );
        }

        //List out all Form Body Values
        body = actionContext.Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
    }

    // Implement Interface and use code to read the body
    // and find your Value matching your Key
}
```